# How do I get the golden key?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

On Find Mii/StreetPass Quest, during the Secret Quest, there is a gold key that unlocks a path in the bottom right part of the map. The key is acquired by beating the final enemy in the game, Dark Emperor, with a certain condition, but there are conflicting versions as to what this condition is.

[A map](http://db.gamefaqs.com/portable/3ds/file/streetpass_mii_plaza_find_mii_2_a.png) in GameFAQs states that you need to finish the final enemy with "25 Miis or less", [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/65609221), however, states that people beat it with 22 Miis and didn't get the key.

So, what is the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

A quote from Dark Toshi from Gamefaqs who has a method of consistently acquiring the golden key

> I took the following path (1-2-5-6-10-11-18-26-27-32-33-34-35-36) to ensure that I didn't get the Silver Key by completing rooms 19 & 25.
>
> I killed the Ultimate Ghost each time with a team of two level 7 reds via combo magic. As a result, the fight with the Dark Emperor always began with the two red miis.
>
> I found that the gold key was awarded when I beat the Dark Emperor with 21 miis (this includes the 2 from the Ultimate Ghost battle) in total during the battle itself.
>
> It was NOT awarded when I used 22, 23, 24, and 25 miis against the Dark Emperor with the same condition (beating the Ultimate Ghost with 2 miis). No potions (Vial of Valor, Dispelling Draft) were used in the fight. The number of miis used prior to the Dark Emperor is irrelevant.
>
> Here are the the details of the 21 and 22 mii runs that I did. I am excluding the data for the runs of 23-25 miis since you didn't get the key with 22 miis. I made sure both red miis were cycled through during the fight with the Ultimate Ghost to ensure no mii was miscounted. The 2 miis from the Ultimate Ghost Fight did not increase the counter during the fight with the Dark Emperor.
>
> ## 21 mii run (Gold Key awarded)
>
> Miis used
>   14 level 7 red
>   1 level 6 red
>   6 level 1 red
>
> 8 level 7's cast combo magic for 39 damage each time (Dark Emp 94 HP left)
>   6 level 7's cast single magic for 12 damage each time (Dark Emp 22 HP left)
>   1 level 6 cast single magic for 10 damage (Dark Emp 12 HP left).
>   6 level 1's cast single magic for 2 damage each (Dark Emp 0 HP left).
>
> Heroes met counter at start of fight: 31
>   Heroes met counter at end of fight: 50
>
> 22 mii run (no key earned)
>
> Miis used
>   14 level 7 red
>   1 level 5 red
>   7 level 1 red
>
> 8 level 7's cast combo magic for 39 damage each time (Dark Emp 94 HP left)
>   6 level 7's cast single magic for 12 damage each time (Dark Emp 22 HP left)
>   1 level 5 cast single magic for 8 damage (Dark Emp 14 HP left).
>   7 level 1's cast single magic for 2 damage each (Dark Emp 0 HP left).
>
> Heroes met counter at start of fight: 39
>   Heroes met counter at end of fight: 59
>
> The only case I that haven't confirmed is what would have happened if I had beaten the Ultimate Ghost with just one mii instead of two.
>
> Hopefully this will put to rest all the debate on how the gold key is obtained.